Not able to upload file to GCP using multer
I'm working on an API to upload files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The API works perfectly on localhost, but when deployed to Firebase Functions, it returns:
400 Bad Request
Here’s my code:
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const multer = require("multer");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const path = require("path");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Initialize Firebase and Cloud Storage
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, "test-keys.json"),
});

// Configure multer for handling file uploads
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: { fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 }, // Limit file size to 10MB
});

// API route to upload a file
app.post("/api/uploadFile", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { bucketName, folder } = req.body;

    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).send("No file uploaded.");
    }
    if (!bucketName || !folder) {
      return res.status(400).send("Bucket name and folder are required.");
    }

    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const filePath = `${folder}/${req.file.originalname}`;
    const blob = bucket.file(filePath);

    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
    });

    blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error uploading file.");
    });

    blobStream.on("finish", () => {
      const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${filePath}`;
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "File uploaded successfully.",
        url: publicUrl,
      });
    });

    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong.");
  }
});

exports.expressApi = functions.https.onRequest(app);

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


What I’ve tried so far:
I tested the API locally, and it works fine.
Tried using dest: path.join(os.tmpdir()) with Multer, but the issue persists after deployment.
Any ideas on what could be causing the issue when running in Firebase Functions?

"but doesn't work when I deploy it on firebase" - what exactly are you doing to deploy this to Firebase?  Please edit the question to show the full code and instructions you're using.  We should be able to copy all that and reproduce the same result.  If you're using Cloud Functions, I don't see that you have any function definition here.  This is not deployable to Firebase without a lot of modifications.

Hi, I have modified the question, I deployed the code in firebase functions, I had some other apis as well which worked when i deploy them, but only the file upload is causing the issue. Would appreciate your help!

You can't use app.listen in Cloud Functions, and you won't see that anywhere in the documentation.  It will do that for you and send the requests to your function.

Upon reviewing, here are my thoughts with your case about what may have caused the issue when running in Firebase functions.

The Firebase Functions' default service account might not have the required permissions to write to the Cloud Storage bucket.
Grant the “Storage Admin” or "Storage Object Admin" role to the service account:

Go to the Google Cloud Console IAM page.

Find the default Firebase service account (<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com).

Assign the Storage Admin/ Storage Object Admin role.



Remove the keyFileName parameter from new Storage();. In Firebase Functions, the file system is read-only except for the /tmp directory. Since you’re using keyFilename: path.join(\_\_dirname, "test-keys.json"), this works locally but fails in Firebase because the \_\_dirname path is not accessible in the deployed environment.
const storage = new Storage();



I hope this information is useful to address your issue.
